# Spring Boot update method that calls delete and add method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So I have a `updateSemester` method that first calls `deleteSemester` then `addSemester`, I'm currently having a problem where it tries to put both `delete` and `add` into the same transaction, the DB will throw `Duplicate entry '6-1' for key 'semester.UniqueSemester'`

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addSemester(Long semesterId, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {

    Set<Semester> semesterList = new HashSet<>();
    semesterRepository.saveAll(semesterList);
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void deleteById(Long semesterId) {

    semesterRepository.deleteBySemesterId(semesterId);
}


public void updateSemesterById(Long semesterId, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    deleteSemesterById(semesterId);
    addSemester(semesterId, startDate, endDate);
}
```

I tried a lot of combination of `@Transactional` but none works.

Comment: why are you trying to delete and then create again an entity instead of just updating it in the DB? are there any reasons for doing that?

Comment: @AndreiTitov is right! Also can you update deleteBySemesterId method signature in you question and what error it throwing

Comment: @Nidhi257 I think this is the best solution here, the `semesterList` is populated with x amount of records depending on the `startDate` and `endDate`. So when the startDate and endDate changed, it's best to just delete all and start over.

Answer (score 1):

let me tell you where you are going wrong here. Here the annotation you have used i.e @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) is correct if there is a transaction is in progress spring will suspend the ongoing transaction and start a new one. But the the transactional annotation wont work since the you are calling deleteSemester and addSemester from a method in same class. This is a pitfall of the spring proxy when you invoke a method which is in the same bean you bypass the proxy which has the interceptor logic,you have to maybe add a new helper class. I am assuming there is a need for you to delete and add a record each time instead of just update.

Comment: `repository.flush()` after `deleteSemesterById()` seems to fix my problem although I don't know if it's good to do that or not.